# Failure at loading GWT library

Tags: gwt, import

I am trying to deploy a bigger GWT project to start working on it. After several problems I finally ran into the following, which I am not able to solve:

Here is a random piece of code:

```
service.getSuggestionOracle(this.suggestionString.getText(), new AsyncCallback<List<Entity>>() {
   @Override
   public void onSuccess(List<Entity> result) {
      suggestionString.setStyleName("searchInput");
      processSuggestionOracle(result);
   }

   @Override
   public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
      suggestionString.setStyleName("searchInput");
      GWT.log("Suggestion fails.");
   }
});
```

Eclipse complains about the two functions onSuccess and onFailure that:

```
The method onSuccess(List<Entity>) of type new AsyncCallback<List<Entity>>(){} must override a superclass method
```

Indeed when I hover over the: `new AsyncCallback<List<Entity>>()` statement, it tells me that `If an RPC is successful, then onSuccess(Object) is called, otherwise onFailure(Throwable) is called.`

I conclude that there IS a superclasses with declarations for onSuccess and onFailure, but the compiler doesn't find it.

I use GWT-2.4.0 and the GWT library is added to the classpath.

The code above is just a random example, there are about 150 similar errors all over the
project. Additionally, there are several imports like com.xind.gwt.dom.client.DOM, 
that can not be resolved.

Does anybody have an idea what I am missing here?

Comment: Have you double-checked the sourcecode you gave here? It doesn't seem valid.

Comment: The snippet is copy-paste from the code (I copied a redundant brace, too, it's gone now), and the code is freshly checked out from the repository. So this should be valid.

Comment: Is your project JDK compliance set to Java 1.6?

Comment: Thank you so much, Strelok! Raising the compliance level to 1.7 made about 150 errors disappear! No it's only 15 to go. :)

Thats the second time I run into this compliance trap. Do you by any chance now why they built in this horrible feature?

Comment: Hmmm ... 1.7 is wrong I think. It should be 1.6. Are you building this against a Java 7 JDK (1.7)? Check Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs, you should have a 1.6 JDK installed like and it should be ticked. If you have Java 7 JDK installed and ticked in there you should go back to 1.6.

Comment: Ok, I tried going back to 1.6, but there seem to be no changes. Why is this significant?

Comment: It's significant, because officially, only Java 6 is supported by GWT. When you say you went back to 1.6 did you mean you've changed the default runtime of Eclipse to the 1.6 JDK or you just changed the compliance level? Also, your GWT uses Eclipse JDT for parsing, so you Eclipse `itself` should be running with a 1.6 JDK. My recommendation is if you have Java 7 installed AT ALL on the computer, just remove it and install the latest 1.6 JDK. Should fix all your problems.

Comment: There is no reason not to use Java 7, it will work perfectly, as long as you don't use Java language constructions introduced in Java 7 in your GWT code. So what are the problems left? the imports? Are these to files in your project or files from an external project?

Comment: Yes, it was the imports left, but I was able to get the whole thing running a few hours ago! Thank you very much for your help, Strelok and Hilbrand! :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities that I could think of:

1. you haven't extended RemoteServiceServlet on the server implementation.
2. or 
   In this code,

public void onSuccess(List result) {

}

you have List as the returned object. Is this a list of objects of a user-defined class or java datatype? If the list is a user-defined type, then you must serialize the corresponding class by implementing java.io.serializable;

Comment: I haven't checked that yet, but as already mentioned: The code is from repository and compiles nicely on the systems of my colleagues.
Plus, this is no isolated problem, but repeats itself in different places all over the code.